# Accented letters disappearing

Tags: accents

Both É (upper case E with accent aigu) and é (lower case E with accent aigu) are disappearing.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Rexx, extendedchars=true, frame=trbl}

\section{Statement of problem}

\subsection{Secondary Problem}

sets bar to REN\'{e} rather than to REN\capitalacute{E}.

\end{document}
```

This happens with both pdflatex and with xelatex.

Changing the source to

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Rexx, extendedchars=true, frame=trbl}

\section{Statement of problem}

\subsection{Secondary Problem}

using \\' and \\capitalacute: sets bar to REN\'{e} rather than to REN\capitalacute{E}.
%Command \capitalacute unavailable in encoding T1. r than to REN\capitalacute

using actual é and É sets bar to RENé rather than to RENÉ.

\end{document}
```

I get the error message

> Command \capitalacute unavailable in encoding T1. r than to
> REN\capitalacute

What package and parameters do I need in order to allow both the symbols and the actual letters?

Comment: The problem you describe can *not* be occuring under pdfLaTeX since pdfLaTeX cannot handle the `fontspec` package.

Comment: The fontspec was an attempt to resolve the problem; it wasn't there originally.

Comment: If I remove `fontspec`, I get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is unclear, but if you load the `fontenc` package with the `T1` option you don't need `\capitalacute`.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Ren\'{e} René 

REN\capitalacute{E} REN\'{E} RENÉ

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a combination of package and parameter that will work with both the commands and the actual characters?

Comment: @shmuel Sorry, but I can't understand.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: @shmuel If you type `REN\'{e}` you shouldn't be expecting to get “RENÉ”.

Comment: The text "sets bar to RENé rather than to RENÉ" is part of the test data rather than the problem description. The problem is how to treat both \'{e} and é as U+00E9 and treat both \capitalacute{E} and É as U+00C9.

Comment: @shmuel Sorry, but I cannot read your mind.

Comment: I quoted the error message; no mind reading required.

Comment: @shmuel Well, believe me: I don't get error messages. You must have a rather outdated TeX distribution (prior to 2018). Do also `\usepackage{textcomp}` if you don't want or can't update.

Comment: I plan to install openSUSE LEAP 15.5 once it goes GA, and that will include a more recent TeX. I'll retest after that. Thanks.